# unsure about asm-offsets.c compilation in U-boot source

Tags: u-boot, gcc4.7

I could see `lib/asm-offset.c` file in u-boot(2014.07) source(another file at `arch/arm/lib/asm-offsets.c`), main function is defined in these files. Initially I got doubht who will call this main function, I checked Makefile, but no entry for this file in Makefile also. After build  there is no object file for this. I could see only `asm-offsets.s` and  `asm-offsets.su` files after build. `asm-offsets.s` is around 1000 lines and `asm-offsets.su` is having only one line - `asm-offsets.c:19:5:main 0       static`. From the `asm-offsets.c` source, it seems it is declaring some variables. Can you please help to understand how this source is embedded in U-boot bin

Comment: Can anyone help to understand the above doubt.

Comment: It seems lib/asm-offsets.c file is used to create generic-asm-offsets.h header file under include/generated/ and arch/arm/lib/asm-offsets.c file is used to create asm-offsets.h header file under include/generated/.

Answer (score 0):

lib/asm-offsets.c file is used to generate header file with definitions for global data size, board info size etc..., These definitions will be used in assembly files.

We can see following lines while building u-boot.

```
  CC      lib/asm-offsets.s
  GEN     include/generated/generic-asm-offsets.h
```

similarly for arch/arm/lib/asm-offsets.c

```
CC      arch/arm/lib/asm-offsets.s
GEN     include/generated/asm-offsets.h
```